# How to plot an indicator on top of another [Pine Script]

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I need some help in pine script. In the charting we can plot multiple indicators on top of one another by `Move to existing pane above` or `Move to existing pane below`. Can we achieve this same functionality programmatically with pine script?

I have added a picture for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In pinescript, you cannot create indicator in the both pane at the same time.

If you indicator is declared with **overlay=true**, the indicator will be added in the pane above.

```
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
```

If your indicator doesn't have overlay=true, the indicator will be added in th pane below.

```
indicator("My script")
```

It is possible to show multiple indicator with one script. 
Simply copy the code of one indicator after the code of the first indicator.
Be carefull, in your code you must only have ONE declaration for indicator,
and each code must use it's own variable.

Comment: I'm not creating indicator in both pane. Please take a look at the picture. There I have 3 indicators applied on top of one another. I want to do the same with pine script, if that's possible.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar yes it is possible to have 3 indicators applied on top of one another in pinescript, did you tried my answer ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar yes it is possible to have 3 indicators applied on top of one another in pinescript, did you tried my answer ?